# Selenium Javascript Get title from Google

Tags: javascript, selenium, driver

All I want to do is something really simple but I'm having such a hard time with it.  I want to retrieve the title from Google and print it using Javascript and driver.

Here's my code:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new Builder().forBrowser('internet explorer').build();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
var title = driver.executeScript("return document.title;");
console.log("Title: " + title);
```

Here's my error:

```
Title: [object Promise]                                                                                                         
(node:5412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): UnsupportedOperationError: Error 404: Not Found                                                                                                    
Not Found                                                                                                               
(node:5412) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The Title: [object Promise] line executes before it can finish getting the title from the website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you.

1st you need to build your driver:

```
let capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.ie();
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();
```

then just do what you need

```
async function () {
   await driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}

async function () {
   var title = await driver.getTitle();
   assert.equal(title, "Google");
});
```

I use async\await syntax instead of promises to make tests more clear and short.